# VSTS backlog items - adding tasks without a project and cross project views

Tags: azure-devops, kanban

Still new to VSTS. Sometimes work or requests come in and our team needs a way of sorting these into areas that will become projects, but not immediately.  Can I create a task without first creating a new team project?

Also, is there a way to see different projects at a higher level than the tasks in one view on a kanban board?  Ive seen some delp docs on dashboards etc, but everything including tasks are all scoped to a team project.  While this makes sense to have these things for a project, but what about higher level views?  At any one time, there might be 4-5 different projects being worked on as well as 2-3 different things that are not part of a project yet.  Maybe VSTS isnt the place for these more general items, but a generic kanban board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "team project" is kind of an antiquated name that doesn't do a great job of accurately describing its purpose. Think of a "team project" as a portfolio of related applications rather than something for a single team, or a single project.

The most common way to address is this to keep *everything* in a single team project. There are a lot of things that don't cross team project boundaries, and trying to force that behavior is a recipe for frustration.

Within a team project, you can create [Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scale/multiple-teams?view=vsts). Each team can have its own backlog, its own iteration schedule, etc. Teams are assigned an area path that they own. If a work item is under their area, it's assigned to that Team.

If you have Team A's area path set to `FooProject/Team A`, then it belongs to that team. A work item under `FooProject/Team A` shows up on that Team's backlog.

From there, you can adjust security permissions and such so that if a person isn't a member of a given Team, they don't have access to see or manipulate other teams' work items.